# uuid.uuid4() not creating random UUID in DJango forms

Tags: django, forms, uuid

I have a product creation form in Django admin space. In the product creation form I have a clean product ID method:

forms.py

```
import UUID
    def clean_pk_product_id(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_product_id = uuid.uuid4()
        return pk_product_id
```

models.py

```
class dboinv_product(models.Model):
    pk_product_id = models.UUIDField(
        default = uuid.uuid4(),
        primary_key=True,
        null=False
    )
```

For some reason, this is not generating a random UUID, it will attempt to use a 'pre-determined' ID. I have attempted to create multiple new objects, and all throw the same error stating that the primary key is not unique, and gives the same UUID > (3e18d2da4f624649a7cfa310108a1421)

Is there something wrong with the way I am handling the validation of this form? I am unsure how Django admin processes these forms...

UPDATE: I do not call validation on this form, it is done by django, as this form is only used for the admin space

Comment: Show the rest of the code. like where you call this method, your models etc

Comment: `default = uuid.uuid4()`, remove the brackets there... `default = uuid.uuid4`

Comment: I do not call this method, django does. This is simply the form rendered in the admin space. Django handles validation on it's own.... it is as if the uuid.uuid4() method is a non-dynamic variable.... the value is stagnant

Comment: removing the brackets changed the value, but it is still not random.... I was able to add one product upon changing the code, but now the same issue occurs but for a new UUID value... uuid.uuid4 is supposed to generate one randomly, correct?

Comment: @AustinHallett not in the method `clean_pk_product_id` remove those brackets from the `default` specified in the model field. Your `clean_pk_product_id` is likely not even being _used_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model you have the default set as follows in your model:

```
default = uuid.uuid4()
```

Here you have *called* `uuid.uuid4` which returns a uuid which is then used as the default. This is **not** what you want. Instead you need to set the default to the function itself as it can take a callable:

```
class dboinv_product(models.Model):
    pk_product_id = models.UUIDField(
        default = uuid.uuid4, # Remove the brackets
        primary_key=True,
        null=False
    )
```

Next as to your function `clean_pk_product_id`, I believe it is never even *used*. I don't suppose you allow the user to enter the `pk_product_id`, which means your form likely doesn't have a field `pk_product_id` hence that method you declare is never even called, and simply the fields default value is used.

---

> **Note**: Class names should ideally be in `PascalCase` not `snake_case`, so `dboinv_product` is not a great name. Have a look at
> [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: wow, amazing. Such a minor issue. Thanks so much for your help!